# Discord Bot with OpenAI Whisper Integration - Inconsistent Transcription

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, openai-whisper

I am working on a **Discord bot** that utilizes the Python Discord library, specifically the **interactions library** which is a framework to build a discord bot, to connect with OpenAI Whisper for transcription. Although it doesn't have an inbuilt method, we have come up with a way to modify the interactions library to provide binary data during recording, which I am then saving to a .pcm file. Subsequently, I read the .pcm file as binary and passed it to the binary_transcribe() function.

```
def binary_transcribe(self, audio_data): 
    audio_data = frombuffer(audio_data, dtype=int16)
    audio_data = audio_data.astype('float32') / 32767.0
    result = self.model.transcribe(audio_data)
    self.p.terminate()
    print("Transcription completed...")
    return result["text"]
```

The issue I am facing is that the Whisper transcription results are inconsistent and incorrect. Even for the same input, the whisper produces different outputs on each run. I'm struggling to identify the source of this problem and would appreciate any guidance on how to achieve consistent and accurate transcription results.
Are there any known considerations or adjustments I should be aware of when using OpenAI Whisper in this context?

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide.

Additional Information:

- Discord Python Library: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
- Interactions Library: https://interactions-py.github.io/interactions.py/
- OpenAI Whisper: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/speech-to-text/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this project ?

https://github.com/m-bain/whisperX/

They talk about :

️ VAD preprocessing, reduces hallucination & batching with no WER degradation